# Trouble configuring grunt bower-install

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I am quite new to the Yeoman workflow(started using Yeoman today).
I am trying to install [grunt bower-install](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install), in order to automate the asset management process.

The problem is that despite the fact I followed the the instructions in the docs to the last of them, when trying to run `grunt bower-install` I get errors.

When trying to run this command from the home DIR, the errors are as following:

```
oleg@ob:~$ !!
Running "bower-install:app" (bower-install) task
Verifying property bower-install.app.src exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "bower-install.app.src" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-01-20 10:17:47 UTC)
loading tasks      3ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 25%
bower-install:app  8ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 67%
Total 12ms
```

After cding into the app directory and running the command again, I get a different error:

```
oleg@ob:~/app$ grunt bower-install
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Unable to read "package.json" file (Error code: ENOENT).
Warning: Task "bower-install" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any help is much more then greatly appreciated!

My Gruntfile.js (within app/ dir) looks as following:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Project configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        // Metadata
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
            '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
            '<%= pkg.homepage ? "* " + pkg.homepage + "\\n" : "" %>' +
            '* Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author.name %>;' +
            ' Licensed <%= props.license %> */\n',
        // Task configuration
        concat: {
            options: {
                banner: '<%= banner %>',
                stripBanners: true
            },
            dist: {
                src: ['lib/<%= pkg.name %>.js'],
                dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '<%= banner %>'
            },
            dist: {
                src: '<%= concat.dist.dest %>',
                dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
            }
        },
        'bower-install': {

          target: {
            // Point to the files that should be updated when
            // you run `grunt bower-install`
            src: ['/home/oleg/index.html'],

            // Optional:
            // ---------
            cwd: '',
            ignorePath: '',
            exclude: [],
            fileTypes: {}
          }
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                curly: true,
                eqeqeq: true,
                immed: true,
                latedef: true,
                newcap: true,
                noarg: true,
                sub: true,
                undef: true,
                unused: true,
                boss: true,
                eqnull: true,
                browser: true,
                globals: {
                    jQuery: true
                }
            },
            gruntfile: {
                src: 'gruntfile.js'
            },
            lib_test: {
                src: ['lib/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js']
            }
        },
        qunit: {
            files: ['test/**/*.html']
        },
        watch: {
            gruntfile: {
                files: '<%= jshint.gruntfile.src %>',
                tasks: ['jshint:gruntfile']
            },
            lib_test: {
                files: '<%= jshint.lib_test.src %>',
                tasks: ['jshint:lib_test', 'qunit']
            }
        }
    });

    // These plugins provide necessary tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-install');

    // Default task
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'qunit', 'concat', 'uglify']);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right to run `grunt` commands from the root directory of your project. However, I believe you're running the wrong `grunt-bower-install` subtask, judging from this error:

```
Running "bower-install:app" (bower-install) task
Verifying property bower-install.app.src exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "bower-install.app.src" missing.
```

If you simply run `grunt bower-install`, it should work. Either that, or rename

```
'bower-install': {
    target: { /* ... */ }
}
```

to...

```
'bower-install': {
    app: { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It tells you that you are missing a package.json file in your project directory ("Error: Unable to read "package.json" file").

As you can see here `pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')` your gruntfile tries to read that file.

So, create package.json, then try again grunt bower-install - that will at least get you started.

More about package.json files: https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html and http://package.json.nodejitsu.com/